# Extension method not accessible from list of derived type

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, extension-methods

I'm working on a little practice project for myself and I'm trying to call this extension method in my tests

```cs
var days = account.Transactions.PassDays(10, Today);
```

which gives me this error

> ```
> CS1929    'List<Transaction>' does not contain a definition for 'PassDays' and the best extension method overload 'PassTime.PassDays(List<Event>, int, DateTime)' requires a receiver of type 'List<Event>'
> ```

The using statement is highlighted, the extension method is declared as

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Day> PassDays(this List<Event> events, int daysToPass, DateTime startTime)
```

The List I'm trying to use it on is of a class that derives from the Event class. Everything I've read suggests this should work.

```cs
public record Transaction : Event
```

```cs
public record Event : IEvent
```

Comment: `List<Transaction>` is not `List<Event>` (and is not derived from) so what did you expected? If you wana make use of covariance then you need to use interface like `IEnumerable`

Comment: Is that because while `Transaction` inherits `Event`, `List<Transaction>` does not inherit `List<Event>`? What would your suggestion be without making it an extension specific to `List<Transaction>` because I'm planning to use the same method for other classes that inherit `Event`. Just saw your edit I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Day> PassDays(this IEnumerable<IEvent> events, int daysToPass, DateTime startTime)
```

fixed this. (`IEvent` was not necessary for this but I made the change in anticipation of it being more useful) maybe someone else can explain why this worked.

Comment: *why this worked* - It's a long read but the relevant bit is at the end; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance